# Why is one lightbulb in a string illuminated?

Tags: parallel, lighting

[image: Photo of only one light illuminated]

I noticed that in various strings of lights only one was illuminated. It seems implausible that all but one out of several hundred blew. What caused this and why did this particular light turn on?

Comment: I think there is too less information to answer this question without speculation, and there is probably neither no way to validate an answer in order to accept it.

Comment: Never seen serial streetlights on cables from street-corners before. But if there enough mutual coupling to power 1 bulb out of say 30  in series. The bulb with the fastest warm-up time draws all the induced voltage ( e.g. 240/30) due to 10:1 PTC effects

Comment: Looks a lovely park not far from the Welsh coast

Comment: How about this:  The lamps are on a photocell-switched circuit, but one lamp is lit constantly to indicate that the circuit is powered.  It's not dark enough to trigger to photocell switch.

Comment: Holiday lights have the so called "shunt wire". The shunt is a small wire wrapped beneath the filament that allows current to continue flowing through the circuit by creating a path of lower resistance than the original path in case the filament opens. For details -> https://www.energy.gov/articles/how-do-holiday-lights-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The intriguing light bulb has caught the attention of Smokey the Bear too.*

There can only be a few possibilities:

- The lamps are spread across several phases or split phases, the other phases are off and all but this lamp has blown. This is very unlikely.
- Some joker has installed a battery powered lamp. This too seems unlikely.

> "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth." Sherlock Holmes.

- The impossible has happened and all have blown but one. This could happen with an overvoltage - by lightning, for example. Some combination of poor contact, tough filament, arcing in another lamp (which would limit the voltage), etc., may be enough to let it survive.

---

Another possibility is that the power is on and that each bulb has its own light sensor (like some streetlights) and this one is the first to switch on. Again, unlikely.

Comment: I'd go with the battery powered hypothesis,  there are available lamps that include a battery back-up

Comment: Are these lamps connected in series or parallel? Or several series strings in parallel?

Comment: looks like parallel festoon fittings to me

Comment: Then the o/v has my vote.  Someone may have fitted a single 275V (very likely 260V) globe as a spare. We had these in Western Australia for a long time and they lasted forever back when we were 250V and the rest of the country 240V.  (almost always higher in both cases).

Comment: What about if someone replaced one of the bulbs with an LED lamp? They can sometimes light up on a much lower voltage.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy may be on to something is the lights are switched by a timer or photocell that relies on passing a small current through the bulbs.  I've seen LEDs light dimly on these and even CFLs can blink.

Comment: I went back when it was brighter ( ideally it would have been darker) and it wasn’t lit, this makes me think that your last suggestion is correct. Great answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with the implausible explanation. All the bulbs are blown except the one.

Most festoon lights use a screw-in socket so all the lights are in parallel:

[image]

It's certainly unlikely in the extreme that the lights are in any way series connected.

I'd suggest that the string was perhaps hit by a truck (or a surge) and a bunch of the lights broke.